# Error with nested IFERROR/VLOOKUP - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

UPD: turns out there was an issue with the reference to Sheet_2, the actual formula is fine, my bad.

I have a problem with nested IFERROR/VLOOKUP in Google Sheets.

There are two sheets - "Sheet_1" and "Sheet_2".
Sheet_1 has three columns: the first column with the transaction amount, the second column with a date, and the third column where the exchange rate for this date needs to be.
Sheet_2  sheet has three columns: the first column has a date, and the second column has the exchange rate for this date.

I want to automate the process of inserting the exchange rate from Sheet_2 into Sheet_1 by using VLOOKUP. The problem is that some transactions are executed on weekends, when there is no set exchange rate and, thus, no value for this date in Sheet_2, so VLOOKUP returns an error.

I tried solving it by using IFERROR - if VLOOKUP doesn't return the exchange rate, IFERROR uses VLOOKUP with the previous date (date-1), or, if this also doesn't work - (date-2).

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(B3; 'Sheet_2'!A8:C38; 2; false); iferror(VLOOKUP((B3-1); 'Sheet_2'!A8:C38; 2; false);iferror(VLOOKUP((B3-2); 'Sheet_2'!A8:C38; 2; false); "?")))
```

The problem is that, well, it's not working.
The formula returns an error even for dates that are definitely present on Sheet_2, and I'm not sure what the problem is. Help please?

Comment: Dates are difficult to match exactly if there is any time component to the date, whether the cell is formatted to show the time or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized example of how previous date(s) exchange rate can be pulled in using `xlookup` match mode factor.

```
=index(xlookup(B2:B11,E2:E8,F2:F8,,-1))
```

[image]